# Programmatically take picture from camera using Volume button in android

Tags: android, android-permissions, android-camera2

I know selfie stick take picture using volume button . I have a screen recording application . While recording  if i open device's existing camera application i want to take picture from camera application automatically . I can press volume button automatically by using below code :

```
@Override
 public void run() {
  try {
   Instrumentation inst = new Instrumentation();
   inst.sendKeyDownUpSync(KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_UP);
  } catch (Exception e) {

  }

 }
}).start()
```

It presses volume button while the camera app is not open . But when the camera app is open it shows : 
**java.lang.SecurityException: Injecting to another application requires INJECT_EVENTS permission**

I know INJECT_EVENTS permission is only work with **system apps** and without system app it can be used in only **rooted device** . But while recording i can take picture with selfie stick . Is there any way to act as selfie stick while camera open from my application (Like press volume button ) . Or any other way ?

**Thanks in advance**

Answer (score -1):

Implement `OnTouchListener` with your activity

```
public class YourActivity extends Activity implements OnTouchListener {
.....
```

Override `onKeyDown` and write your action inside it

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_DOWN) 
        || (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_UP)){
        //Write your camera capture action
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer . But this is not what i am looking for .